# Count appended data

Tags: javascript, jquery, vbscript

i have data that is appended each time a user click on a button, but I want to know the number  of data that is appended whenever I click .

My data contains a part of a table (a bunch of ) and I want to know how many rows are in there

```js
function openFromB(lastLoadedIndex) {
  lastLoadedIndex = (typeof(lastLoadedIndex)=='undefined') ? '' : lastLoadedIndex;

  jQuery.get('liste.asp?from_item='+ lastLoadedIndex +'&param='+(new Date()).getTime(), function(data) { 
    jQuery('.liste).append(data);
    if (data) {
      document.getElementById('load').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('more').style.display = 'block';  
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Would `data.length` be what you're after?

Comment: data.lenght gives how many characters are in there. My data contains a part of a table (a bunch of <tr>) and I want to know how many rows are in there

Comment: There is a typo on this line `jQuery('.liste).append(data);` should be `jQuery('.liste').append(data);` the class selector string is not properly terminated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$.parseHTML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) (jQuery) to parse a string into an array of DOM nodes.

```
var $html = $.parseHTML(data);
```

And then you can get your row count like you would any other object in jQuery:

```
var len = $("table tr",$html).length;
```

And to make a change to an element inside:

```
$("#load",$html).css("display","none");
```

Or for hiding you can just do:

```
$("#load",$html).hide();
```

**NOTE:** Make sure you're providing valid/properly structured html to `$.parseHTML()`, otherwise there can be unexpected results.